# Menu on NavigationLink is not tapable

Tags: swiftui

How can I put a `Menu` on a `NavigationLink` destination? This approach opens only the destination and never the menu when I tap on it.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink (
            destination: Text("Hello")
            label: { 
                ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing){
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                    Menu {
                        Button("Order Now", action: {print("1")})
                        Button("Adjust Order", action: {print("2")})
                    } label: {
                        Label("Options", systemImage: "paperplane")
                    }
                }
            })
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) 
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Just to clarify: The Menu is in the top right corner. When I tap on this menu button, the menu should appear. Otherwise when I tap on the rest of the view the destination of the NavigationLink should be opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a "solution". A little bit hacky, but it works so far. I just wrapped the menu in a button:

```
Button(action: {/*do something*/}, label: {
    Menu {
        Button("Option 1", action: {print("1") })
        Button("Option 2", action: {print("2") })
    } label:  {Text("Menu") }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. third time's a charm.. so they say!

I made it harder than what it needed to be but that is a working example of `Menu` and I learned from this myself

```
    import SwiftUI

struct navViewTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
         
            VStack {
              Text("Hello World")
            }.navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                    Menu {
                                        Button("Option 1", action: {doSomething() })
                                        Button("Option 2", action: {doSomething() })
                                    } label:  {Text("Menu") }
            )
        }
        }
    private func doSomething() { }
}

struct navViewTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        navViewTest()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use the `Menu` to navigate to a view. I just have some buttons that navigate to a specific view and each button should has an `Menu` on top of it.

Comment: @Erik okay, check the newest post, Im going to further edit it with more details

Comment: Thank you, but your second solution is unfortunately not what I'm looking for. Just to clarify: The Menu is in the top right corner. When I tap on this menu button, the menu should appear. Otherwise when I tap on the rest of the view the destination of the NavigationLink should be opened.

Comment: where should the menu appear, in the top right corner as well or you want the menu in the center of the view?

Comment: At the right top corner of the navigation link, so at the position where I tapped on it

Comment: @Erik Okay, one last time! Check the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229889/discussion-between-sergio-bost-and-erik).